# Child Pages Loop

Tags: loop, pages, child-pages, post-class

If anyone can help that'd be great.

I've found a snippet of code that I've used which is pretty much doing what I want it to do, which lists out subpages of the parent, adds a thumbnail if there is one, and added a custom excerpt.

However, the problem is that I can't add individual `<?php post_class(); ?>` to a div inside the loop, its using the class from the parent and repeating for the subpages.

```
<?php
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."    AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');    ?>
<?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>

<?php
// Must be inside a loop.
if ( has_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID) ) {
get_the_post_thumbnail('page-thumb-mine');
}
//  else {
//  echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/icon-cropped.png" />';
//  }
?>

<div <?php post_class(); ?>>    
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'page-thumb-mine'); ?>
<h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php     echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?></a></h3>
<?php echo excerpt(28); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; endif;
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the problem is that some template tags rely on the global `$post` variable. Using `setup_postdata()` as you are now, will not alter `$post`. If you replace all the instances of `$pageChild` with `$post`, everything *should* work.

However, I would strongly recommend using the WP_Query class and setting up your post data with 'the_post()' instead. Here is the equivalent of your code, but with WP_Query:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
);

$child_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php while ( $child_query->have_posts() ) : $child_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?>>  
        <?php  
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail('page-thumb-mine');
        }
        ?>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Note: I cleaned up a few other things in your posted code. Also, I swapped out your custom `excerpt()` function with `the_excerpt()` so the example code works for anyone that wants to copy/paste it.

References:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata

Comment: @BigBabel You are a star, that works brilliantly, sorry about the messy code, I was trying all sorts of things and couldn't remember the original state. - Yes, I've got a custom excerpt function in my functions file. - Anyway, thank you so much again, really appreciate the time you took to reply.

Comment: This line of code seems to break this loop:
<?php echo excerpt(28); ?>
I removed it and the example code worked great.

Comment: Maybe remove that line from the answer since most users get here via Google and just looking for code that loops child-pages.

Comment: @RichardLindhout I had hoped the note I included about that function would be enough to keep people from running into problems. However, considering the age of this question, it definitely wouldn't hurt to make the code example more generic now. Thanks!